# How to inject user credentials in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, credentials

When I use the Jenkins Credentials Binding plugin I can inject global credentials without any problems.

When I use a parameterized build, I can also inject credentials stored in the user profile ( -> Credentials). However this is only possible if the user actively clicks on the build ("Build with parameters") and then selects the credentials.

Is it possible to always inject credentials from the user profile that have a certain ID?

My usecase is that the Job should perform some actions on our issue tracking system using the user-specific credentials of the user who started the job.

Comment: you can create a script takes hash (user and password in a file) to filter the user (env variable has the user triggered the build) and get password and then inject to variable.. kindly check for the alternative way instead of injecting the password which highly not recommended .

Comment: Try out this and let me know. so we can update this as the solution for now

Comment: @DevD  I disagree, I think question is spot-on: (1) an attacker can put malicious env variables if they can create their own job (2) no env variable identifies the user who triggered the build (3) credentials can be SSH agent keys, which are much more secure than a plaintext password.

Comment: Kubanczyk .. injecting password from env variables itself prone to hacks.. instead you can  workflow /env inject and build a groovy  script to inject password from encrypted file